# Detect when expand/collapse (plus/minus) icon is clicked in JTree

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtree

I'm writing a `MouseListener` to replace the default clicking behaviour in the `JTree`. How can I tell when this icon is clicked so I can expand the row myself? (I know this is default behaviour, but I'm replacing the default `MouseListener` with my own `MouseListener`).

Here's my code:

```
    // Custom mouse listener for the tree
    MouseListener treeMouseListener = new MouseAdapter()
    {
      public void mousePressed (MouseEvent e)
      {
          TreePath path = cameraTree.getPathForLocation(e.getX(), e.getY());

          // Do some methods based on what was clicked
          ...
      }
    };
```

The TreePath returned by `cameraTree.getPathForLocation(e.getX(), e.getY())` is null when clicking on the +/- icon. How can I tell when that +/- icon is clicked?

Comment: Why?  This seems like a classic [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/155831).

Comment: BTW - is the tree intended to enable expanding/collapsing nodes using **keyboard input**?

Comment: @Andrew Now that you've mentioned it, this is an XY problem. My "actual" problem instead is: being able to select multiple items in the JTree. And this can be done with a TreeSelectionListener. Thanks for the insight

Comment: @diddles Did you find what you want? Would you please share?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using JTree, you could use a TreeSelectionListener.
More info here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html